# Why does Microsoft Word 2016 (16.0.5426.1000)MSO (16.0.5422.100) 32-bit hang when executing these 2 macros?

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2016

Create the test document from an empty document by executing:

```
Sub CreateHangDocument()
    With ActiveDocument.Tables.Add(ActiveDocument.Range, 2, 3)
        .Descr = "A"
        .AllowAutoFit = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Then hang the application:

```
Sub Hang()
    Application.UndoRecord.StartCustomRecord "Hang"
    With ActiveDocument
        .PageSetup.LeftMargin = 45.35
        With .Tables(1).Rows
            .Add .Item(1)
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Every time I had to terminate the process.

It does not matter whether the macros are executed from the Macro dialogue in the main application or by placing the cursor in the macro code in the editor and pressing F5 (run). It is a minimal test case as far as I know. Remove any part and it will not hang. Combine the functions into one and it will not hang. Replacing LeftMargin with RightMargin makes no difference.

Comment: Just a guess, but AFAICR Word operations that involved printer drivers could be unreliable, to say the least. Could be worth doing something like switching default printer just to check. FWIW this code does not cause a problem with the current version of WinWord available to me (2401, Build 17231.20084 (click-to-Run). Not sure I can replicate something closer to your version, will have a look.